# Ways to use SMOTE via pytorch

Tags: pytorch, smote

dddI want to use SMOTE in my code, most of which is written in Pytorch based python.

I know Pytorch provides like [Sampler](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#data-loading-order-and-sampler), but it seems that it is literally a 'sampler', which samples data from a dataset randomly and provides several features about sampling, but possibly not SMOTE.

By SMOTE, I mean the oversampling technic that is illustrated in the very [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1813), which oversamples minority data from linear combinations of two minorities.

[This person](https://www.kaggle.com/discussions/general/304848) seemed to have the same idea as mine, but got the wrong answer. And [this person](https://github.com/chingisooinar/SMOTE-Pytorch) seem to write his SMOTE code, based on pytorch. Is the last one who make his own code of pytorch for SMOTE is best?